# Persistent subscriber in Firebase

Tags: elasticsearch, firebase

Is there built-in support or any way of implementing a persistent subscription in Firebase?

I need to set up a backend which reacts to certain events in my Firebase database. If the backend has crashed or is being restarted I need it to catch up with anything that has happened while it was down.

For example, I want to re-index certain objects in ElasticSearch when they change. If the backend is down I need to re-index any changed objects when the backend comes back up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is built in for that, although you can definitely build it on top of Firebase by adding a `isIndexed` or `isDirty` property to the items.

But the more common approach is to stuff the items that need to re-indexed into a queue and use a worker process that removes them from the queue when they've been handled. I highly recommend using [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) for that.

Comment: firebase-queue looks like a good approach, thanks! Is there a way of atomically updating a node and posting something into the queue at the same time?

Comment: Yup. Have a look here https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html